# How do i find this div using Xpath

Tags: xpath

On this Url there is text i want to mine

http://www.mefik.co.il/provider.asp?provider_id=10757

I'm looking for the class 'big_obj_px_news_page'

tried all kinds of xpath options.

any help ?

Comment: You've tried all kinds of xpath options? That's great! Maybe you can show us some.

Comment: Sorry you're right ofcourse:

//div[@class=contains('big_obj_px_news_page')] <== null
//div[contains('big_obj_px_news_page')] <== fails
//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' big_obj_px_news_page ')] <== null

Comment: turns out i had a stupid bug that sent my client to the wrong url, hence 248 divs vs 236.... it works now that i got my head outta my a$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you install Firefox+Firebug+Firepath to validate your xpaths. Your xpaths were close, but not enough.

```
//div[@class='big_obj_px_news_page']

// or if this div may have more class names
//div[contains(@class, 'big_obj_px_news_page')]
```

Comment: `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                    document.LoadHtml(html);
  var cl = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(Xpath);
//c1 returns null
 `

Comment: @MickeyPerlstein: The xpaths above are definitely for sure correct. You need to check what HtmlAgilityPack's SelectNodes wants.

Comment: @MickeyPerlstein: If you try `//div`, how many nodes will be returned?

Comment: @MickeyPerlstein: Your third is actually correct by the way. The first two are not. Something else is wrong rather than xpath. I can only get 236 divs from the page.

Comment: @MickeyPerlstein: If you try `var Nodes = from x in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.DescendantNodes()
                  where x.Name == "div" && x.Attributes["class"].Value == "big_obj_px_news_page"`, what would you get?

Comment: object reference not set to an instance of an object, which is kinda the same as null @user1177636

Comment: Firepath says : .//*[@id='left_ip']/div[1]/div[2]
   but it still returns null :(

Answer (score 0):

I created a unit test with the following code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Xml;

namespace HtmlAgilityPackTests
{
    [TestClass]
     public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(File.ReadAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\test.html"));
            var item = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[contains(@class,     'big_obj_px_news_page')]");
            Assert.IsNotNull(item);
        }
    }
}
```

This test passes with the exact html on the page provided.  In your code you wrote `var item = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(Xpath)`, are you typing the exact xpath string above, or are you trying to use an xpath object?

If you're using an XPath object, it could be that you are setting up your XPath object incorrectly.  The only other option I see is that you are not loading your Html correctly.  In the unit test code above "test.html" contains the full html source from the page you provided, and resides in the same directory as the c# source code.  In the test.html file properties window in Visual Studio, I've set "Copy to Output Directory" to "copy if newer".  It's build action is "Content".

Perhaps if you describe how you're loading your html, we can be of further assistance.

Comment: this.Xpath = "//*[contains(@class, 'big_obj_px_news_page')]";
//returns null

Comment: sorry about that, I started my post before your comments above were posted.  I've altered my answer, taking the new information into account.